# How to cache Ajax Response in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using two div(s). In the first div, all the WordPress users are shown on a page, with "ADD" Button Option. By adding Users, they get added to the second div using Ajax. But I want to cache the result shown in the second div. The code for users template are as follows-

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Users
*/
?>
<style>
.container{
  width: 800px;
}
.left{
  float:left;
  width: 300px;
  background: ##66CDAA;
  border-right: thick-solid #fff;
}
.right{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  background: powderblue;
}
</style>
<?php
 get_header(); ?>
 <div id="primary" class="content-area">
   <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="left" id="xyz">
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Gravatar Image</th>
         <th>Add to Div</th>
       </tr>
     <?php
      $sql ="SELECT * FROM wp_users";
      $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      foreach( $results as $result ){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td id="<?php echo $result->ID; ?>">
          <?php echo $result->display_name; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
          <php echo get_avatar( $result->user_email, 42); ?>
          </td>
          <td>
          <input type="button" class="submit" data-id="<?php echo $result->ID; ?>" data-name="<?php echo $result->display_name; ?>" data_image="<?php echo get_avatar_url($result->user_email, 42); ?>" value="ADD"><p style="display:none;">Added</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
          }
        ?>
        </table>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
   <p>Added Users</p>
   <table>
   <tr>
     <th>Name<th>
     <th>Image</th>
   </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
 </div>


</main>
     </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now, in ajax.js I have the following code:

```
    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".submit").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).css("display", "none");
      $(this).closest("td").find("p").css("display", "block");
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      var name = $(this).data('name);
      var image = $(this).data('image');

      $.ajax({
          url: ajax_url,
          method: 'post',
          data: { action: 'work', id:id, name: name, image:image},
          success: function(response){
              var test = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
              name1 = test.myname;
              url1: test.url;
              id: test.id;
          $('.table').append('<tr id=" ' + id1+ ' "><td>' + name1 + '</td><br><td><img src=" ' + url1 + ' "></td><td><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel"></td></tr>');
          $('.cancel').on("click", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var id2 =$(this).closest.("tr").attr('id');
          $('td[id=' + id2 + ']').closest('tr').find('p').css('display', 'none');
          $('td[id=' + id2 + ']').closest('tr').find('input').css('display', 'block');
          $(this).closest("tr").hide();
        })
      }
    })
  })
})
})(jQuery);
```

Now, In ajax.php, I have the function which is as follow:

```
function work() {
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $image_url = $_POST['image'];

  $myObj->myname = $name;
  $myObj->url = $image_url;
  $myObj->id = $id;

  $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
  echo $myJSON;
  wp_die();
}
```

I want to add users to the second div using Ajax and also want to cache the result for some time. Also, suggest if there is a better way of hiding Add button or can I apply a condition to check whether a particular user has been added should not be added twice. But my primary question is that how can I cache ajax result.

Comment: create `js` array and `set/get` in `localstorage` , also check `$.inArray()` to check for existing user data before adding them to localStorage

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you, go through the below code snippet**

```
// ask the browser to cache this response
$expires = 60 * 15;        // 15 minutes
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: maxage=' . $expires);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires) . ' GMT');
```

Comment: Where should I place this code. I want to cache the appended response to the second div. will it work for that?